# Remmina installation error

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, remmina

I am taking a Google Technical Support fundamental course. For a part of this course, I will be connecting my VM via RDP. But when I execute these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt update
sudo apt install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-spice
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-enterprise : Depends: mongodb-enterprise-server but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: mongodb-enterprise-mongos but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: mongodb-enterprise-tools but it is not going to be installed
 remmina : Depends: remmina-common (= 1.3.6+ppa201908270749.r88fcce0.dcd85008~ubuntu18.04.1) but 1.2.0-rcgit.29+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 remmina-plugin-spice : Depends: libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 (>= 0.32) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libspice-client-gtk-3.0-5 (>= 0.32) but it is not going to be installed
 remmina-plugin-vnc : Depends: remmina (= 1.2.0-rcgit.29+dfsg-1ubuntu1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I  tried these commands too in order to resolve the issue, but had no luck.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

---

```
$ apt-cache policy mongodb-enterprise 
mongodb-enterprise: 
 Installed: 4.2.0 
 Candidate: 4.2.0
 Version table:
 *** 4.2.0 500 
     500 repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-enterprise/4.2/multiverse amd64 Packages 
     100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a PPA? Remmina is in [main](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=remmina). What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Thanks for responding . My Ubuntu version is 18.04. I was taking the quiz in coursera site .This course is run by Google .It redirect me to qwiklabs page . There I was instructed to follow these instructions Option 4: Linux users: Connecting to your VM via RDP

In this section, you will use Remmina to connect to your windows instance using its external IP address. Open Remmina in your Linux machine. Linux users can install Remmina if it is not pre-installed.

    Open Remmina.

    ............................................................

Comment: https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/#sabayon-gentoo-binary-based

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy mongodb-enterprise`. Do you really need it? Do you have any configured MongoDB databases?

Comment: I have MongoDB cluster installed in my machine.I tried Mongo Shell to write queries that's when I think I messed it up .I don't think I need MongoDB now .So either remove or reinstall will do .But it will be perfect if I can fix MongoDB and install Remmina.

Comment: pt-cache policy mongodb-enterprise
mongodb-enterprise:
  Installed: 4.2.0
  Candidate: 4.2.0
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.0 500
        500 http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-enterprise/4.2/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: I'm not familiar with MongoDB and its repositories, but it seems that you have missed some of its repositories. Check the https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise page for details.

Comment: Okay. Do you know or have any idea about how I can remove mongo package from my machine completely and resume installation of Remmina ? I tried sudo service mongod stop and sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org* those two commands as well.

Answer (score 0):

As was said comments, we can remove MongoDB with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-enterprise*
```

Then for most of the use-cases you can use Remmina from *main* pocket of repositories.

So you have to remove the PPA with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
```

and install Remmina from ordinary *main* repository:

```
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-spice
```

Comment: I think it has something do with mongodb-enterprise dependence issue .I am bit stuck . I tried installation or removing mongodb but  no luck .